# asp.net MVC Webgrid Action Column not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I want to have two delete and edit َAction Buttons in my webgrid together and in one column. But there is a problem,Help me, where is the problem؟!

```html
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Machinary.Brand)
@Code
    Dim wg As New WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage:=10, canPage:=True, canSort:=True, ajaxUpdateContainerId:="wg1")
    Dim rowIndex = ((wg.PageIndex + 1) * wg.RowsPerPage) - (wg.RowsPerPage - 1)
End Code
<section Class="panel">
    <br />
    <header Class="panel-heading">Brands</header>
   
    <div Class="panel-body pull-left">
        @Using (Html.BeginForm("BrandList", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            @Html.TextBox("strName", Nothing, New With {.class = "form-control", .PlaceHolder = "جستجو"})
                @<Button type="submit" value="" style="display: none"></Button>
        End Using

    </div>
  
    <div>
        
        @wg.GetHtml(tableStyle:="table table-bordered table-hovor", mode:=WebGridPagerModes.All,
                          htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "wg1", .class = "Grid"},
                          firstText:="<<",
                          lastText:=">>",
                          footerStyle:="table-pager",
                          columns:=
                          wg.Columns(wg.Column("Name", "Title"),
                          wg.Column(header:="Actions", format:=Function(item) New HtmlString() {
                          Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.id}),
                          Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.id})})))
    </div>
</section>
```

[This image shows the code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeFNZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. The modified codes are as follows

```
  @wg.GetHtml(tableStyle:="table table-bordered table-hovor", mode:=WebGridPagerModes.All,
                                               htmlAttributes:=New With {.id = "wg1", .class = "Grid"},
                                               firstText:="<<",
                                               lastText:=">>",
                                               footerStyle:="table-pager",
                                               columns:=
                                               wg.Columns(wg.Column("Name", "Title"),
                                               wg.Column(header:="Actions", format:=Function(item) New HtmlString(
                                               Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.id}).ToString +
                                               Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.id}).ToString))))
```